# How to get all rows with common value

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have been trying to get all the rows that has the same value in my DB, I am trying to get it by laravel controller, I have a table with a column name uuid which has uuid of users, there can be multiple rows with the same uuid, I want to get all the rows data with the same uuid, currently I am only getting the first row data.

here is my controller function:

```
public function show($id)
    {
        $cartProduct = add_product_cart::where('uuid', $id)->first();
        if (!$cartProduct) {
            return new ErrorResource('Data not found');
        }
        return new InvestmentResource($cartProduct);
    }
```

I use the api like this:

```
http://localhost:8000/api/investment/1234

//1234 is the uuid

//I get the payload like this:

 "data": {
        "id": 1,
        "uuid": "1234",
        "email": "test2@gmail.com",
        "product_name": "test product",
        "product_price": "5000",
    },
    "status": true
}
```

I am able to get the first row with first() function, but when I use get() then I get this error:

```
Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance.
```

In api.php I have:

```
Route::get('investment/{id}', 'InvestmentController@show');
```

InvestmentResource.php file

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class InvestmentResource extends JsonResource
{
    public function __construct($resource)
    {
        parent::__construct($resource);
        $this->resource = $resource;
    }

    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'uuid' => $this->uuid,
            'email' => $this->email,
            'product_name' => $this->product_name,
            'product_price' => $this->product_price,
        ];
    }

    public function with($request) {
        return [
            'status'=> true,
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `InvestmentResource`?

Comment: JSON Resource file to send Array

Comment: I suspect your error is in `InvestmentResource`. `->get()` will return a collection but perhaps your `InvestmentResource` expects a single `Item`? Posting the code for how your `InvestmentResource` works might clear that up.

Comment: I have added my resource file in my question.

Comment: That expects a single resource, you want to use a [resource collection](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources#resource-collections) to transform your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance.`
The error is due to the fact that `get()` method returns an array(collection with indexes) in response.
So in order to access `id` now you will have to use `$cartProduct[0]->id` of loopover the `$cartProduct` to get all `ids`

**Update**
You can replace your function with the following one.

```
public function show($id)
    {
        $cartProduct = add_product_cart::where('uuid', $id)->get();
        if (!$cartProduct) {
            return new ErrorResource('Data not found');
        }
        return InvestmentResource::collection($cartProduct);
    }
```

Use the collection method if multiple records exist in your collection(data).

Comment: can u share a snippet?

Comment: Need to confirm first that do you need a single record or multiple records?

Comment: multiple records with same UUID

Comment: Perfect answer, that did the trick, thanks alot @yasir gakhar

Answer (score 0):

use `get()` instead of `first()`.

Like this:

```
$cartProduct = add_product_cart::where('uuid', $id)->get();
```

Also change the following to avoid error as you can't use `!` operator to validate array collection:

```
if (count($cartProduct) == 0) {
        return new ErrorResource('Data not found');
    }
```

Comment: getting this error `Exception: Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance. in file E:\Xampp\htdocs\logicfinance\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Traits\EnumeratesValues.php on line 860`

Comment: Can you edit the question and add the code of the file in which you are passing/processing the data?

Comment: I only have a controller that is using only the `show()` method which I have added in my question and there is a resource file `InvestmentResource` that is giving the payload as I have added in the question. i am calling the method by this api `Route::get('investment/{id}', 'InvestmentController@show');`, its giving the payload as expected with `first()` method but its not returning the same with `get()`, its giving the above error.